# How do you kill a running process in a bashscript without killing the script?

Tags: c, bash, shell, sh

How do you kill a running process in a bash script without killing the script?

#### Goal

So... I need to kill a running process to continue with the execution of my script.

Here´s a stripped down version of my script:

```
# Setup
echo "Use ctrl+C to stop gathering data..."
./logger
#------------------
echo "Rest..."
```

I need to be able to kill ./logger without killing my script

#### Expected vs Actual Results

I was expecting a result like this:

```
Use ctrl+C to stop gathering data...
^C
Rest...
```

but it stops when I kill the program

```
use ctrl+C to stop gathering data...
^C
```

The `./logger` command is a C program that already handles the `SIGINT` signal (`Ctrl + C`) but it won't stop until it receives it.
Is there a way to stop the program without killing my script?

The C Program is not important but it looks something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int flag = 1;

void handler(int i)
{
     flag = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    while(flag)
    {
       usleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `sigaction` instead of `signal` as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i dont know what you mean but im only running one command at a time in my script.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the `./logger` line?  Is there a reason you need it to run in a subshell?

Comment: More important question: Have you set the `-e` flag at the top of your script?

Comment: @DanielWalker sorry im new to scripting in shell, but the whole command was this one. `$(\time -o $LOG -a -f 'Total Time Gathering Data: %E\n' ./freq_logger $DIR >> $LOG)`

Comment: Try stripping the bash script down to its essentials.  For starters, have a script that just runs your C program and then put a simple command like `echo Check` on the next line.  See if that works.  What you need is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type control-C at the terminal where the script is running, the signal goes to all the processes — the logger program and the script.  And the script terminates because you've not told it to ignore signals while the logger is run.  You can do that using the [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) command but you'll need to undo the trapping before running the C program. See the Bash manual on [Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals) too.

For example, I have a program `dribbler` that generates messages, one every second by default, but it is configurable.  I'm using it as a surrogate for your `./logger` program.  The `-m` options specifies the message; the `-n` option requests that the messages are numbered, and the `-t` option specifies output to standard output (instead of a file which it writes to by default).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# SO 6418-0134

program="dribbler -t -n -m Hello"
echo "About to run '$program' command"

trap "" 2
(trap 2; $program)

echo "Continuing after '$program' exits"
sleep 1
echo "But not for long"
```

The sub-shell is necessary.  When I run that script (`trapper.sh`), I get, for example:

```
$ bash trapper.sh
About to run 'dribbler -t -n -m Hello' command
0: Hello
1: Hello
2: Hello
3: Hello
^CContinuing after 'dribbler -t -n -m Hello' exits
But not for long
$
```

Incidentally, POSIX defines a command [`logger`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html) that writes messages using the [`syslog()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html) function(s) to the `syslog` daemon.

It might also be worth reviewing the Q&A about [Sending SIGINT to forked exec process which runs a script does not kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58473685/15168), especially the accepted answer and its links to Q&A on other Stack Exchange sites, as it matters that you and I both executed a C program, not a shell script.

Comment: If you do `trap true 2`, sub-shell is no more necessary.